# DOMDocument::validate() problem

Tags: php, xml, xhtml, domdocument

I have a big problem with the PHP DOMDocument::validate() who seems to ask the DTD systematically.

It is a big problem when I whant to validate, for example, an XHTML document [as explained here](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic).

As w3.org seems to reject all request from a PHP server, it's impossible to validate my document with this method...

Is there any solution for that ?

Thanks by advance

[EDIT] Here is some precisions :

/var/www/test.php :

```
<?php
$implementation = new DOMImplementation();

$dtd = $implementation->createDocumentType
       (
         'html',                                     // qualifiedName
         '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN',   // publicId
         'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-'
           .'transitional.dtd'                       // systemId
       );

$document = $implementation->createDocument('', '', $dtd);

$document->validate();
```

[http://]127.0.0.1/test.php :

```
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
 in /var/www/test.php on line 14

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" in /var/www/test.php on line 14

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Could not load the external subset "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" in /var/www/test.php on line 14
```

Related question :

- [How to import XML string in a php `DOMDocument` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4081090/492638) (solved)

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. `DOMDocument::validate` validates the document based on the loaded document's DTD.

Comment: For exemple, if I provide this DTD : http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd, when I call DOMDocument::validate(), PHP send a request to get the file, but w3.org reply systematically with a 403 Forbidden or a 503 Service Unavailable, and PHP send me the warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

Comment: I see, yes. There is a bug open for it: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48080

Comment: I know, and it's very old, but is there any solution ? (and the difference with this bug report is that w3.org deliberately stop to permit request from PHP because of its comportment...)

Comment: I guess the only way around this is to have a DTD at the server and then change the systemId to validate against that instead.

Comment: At this point, I prefer change the etc/host of my server... But the problem is the same : no caching, and request each time I validate...

Comment: I've added a comment providing your link to the w3 blog post to the bug report. Maybe that will get it some more attention. Good question btw.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So it does not seem to have a solution yet...

Comment: I did some more digging. See provided answer below. You can use a stream context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like pointed out in the comments, there is a Bug/FeatureRequest for `DOMDocument::validate` to accept the DTD as a string:

- http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48080

You could host the DTD yourself and change the `systemId` accordingly or you can provide a custom stream context to any loading done through libxml. For instance, providing a UserAgent will get around the W3C's blocking. You could also add proxy this way. See

- [`libxml_set_streams_context()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php) and
- [list of available HTTP context options](http://de.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

Example:

```
$di = new DOMImplementation;
$dom = $di->createDocument(
    'html',
    'html',
    $di->createDocumentType(
        'html',
        '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN',
        'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'
    )
);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

var_dump($dom->validate());
```

This would output

```
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element html content does not follow the DTD, expecting (head , body), got  

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element html namespace name for default namespace does not match the DTD 

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Value for attribute xmlns of html is different from default "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Value for attribute xmlns of html must be "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 

bool(false)
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! It doesn't solve the problem of systematic request without caching (not very fair for w3 but it's not necessary to validate a document each time it is served), but I can now validate my documents. Thank you ^^

Comment: @GQyy actually, thanks for asking the question. It made me learn something new about DOM today, too ;)