# PHP DOMDocument error Entity 'nbsp' not defined

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I use DOMDocument for editing some HTML files, but some of theme have in their names spaces. So DOMDocument automaticly change the spaces to %20 and then can't find them.

This is how looks the error exactly:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Entity 'nbsp' not defined in file:///C:/Path/To/The/File/01%20c%2040-1964.html, line: 11 in C:/Path/To/class.php on line 51
```

How to repair this error?

Comment: If not load but append XML data and getting this error, there is a related question: [DOMDocument appendXML with special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4645738/367456)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) instead of `load()`. That's what it has been made for. HTML is not XML.

XML does not know the named entity `&nbsp;`. However if you use loadHTML, the XML parser will get the HTML named entities loaded so the error goes away.

See as well: [XML parser error: entity not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805050/xml-parser-error-entity-not-defined).

Comment: I have XML with HTML tags not properly inserted into it. I want to load it using load(), because it's XML. What can i do with that?

Comment: This doesn't work if the user is working with HTML snippets or incomplete documents.

Answer (score 7):

If you load xml - use htmlentities() with flag ENT_XML1.

```
$offerXml->addChild('name', htmlentities($name, ENT_XML1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to parse a XHTML snippet that contains HTML entities like `&nbsp;`.

The example is from a piece of code that parses such XHTML exported from Confluence API, including custom elements like `<ac:structured-macro>`. This is why you need to set up namespaces. Change or remove the `xmlns` attributes to suit your use case.

```
$snippet = '<p>hello&nbsp;world</p>';

$entitydefs = XML_HTML_DEFS;

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
$entitydefs
]>
<root
  xmlns:ac="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ac/"
  xmlns:ri="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ri/"
  xmlns="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/">
  $snippet
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

where `XML_HTML_DEFS` is this (you can remove the ones you know won't occur):

```
const XML_HTML_DEFS = <<<ENTITIES
<!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
<!ENTITY lt "&#60;">
<!ENTITY gt "&#62;">
<!ENTITY Agrave "&#192;">
<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;">
<!ENTITY Acirc "&#194;">
<!ENTITY Atilde "&#195;">
<!ENTITY Auml "&#196;">
<!ENTITY Aring "&#197;">
<!ENTITY AElig "&#198;">
<!ENTITY Ccedil "&#199;">
<!ENTITY Egrave "&#200;">
<!ENTITY Eacute "&#201;">
<!ENTITY Ecirc "&#202;">
<!ENTITY Euml "&#203;">
<!ENTITY Igrave "&#204;">
<!ENTITY Iacute "&#205;">
<!ENTITY Icirc "&#206;">
<!ENTITY Iuml "&#207;">
<!ENTITY ETH "&#208;">
<!ENTITY Ntilde "&#209;">
<!ENTITY Ograve "&#210;">
<!ENTITY Oacute "&#211;">
<!ENTITY Ocirc "&#212;">
<!ENTITY Otilde "&#213;">
<!ENTITY Ouml "&#214;">
<!ENTITY Oslash "&#216;">
<!ENTITY Ugrave "&#217;">
<!ENTITY Uacute "&#218;">
<!ENTITY Ucirc "&#219;">
<!ENTITY Uuml "&#220;">
<!ENTITY Yacute "&#221;">
<!ENTITY THORN "&#222;">
<!ENTITY szlig "&#223;">
<!ENTITY agrave "&#224;">
<!ENTITY aacute "&#225;">
<!ENTITY acirc "&#226;">
<!ENTITY atilde "&#227;">
<!ENTITY auml "&#228;">
<!ENTITY aring "&#229;">
<!ENTITY aelig "&#230;">
<!ENTITY ccedil "&#231;">
<!ENTITY egrave "&#232;">
<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;">
<!ENTITY ecirc "&#234;">
<!ENTITY euml "&#235;">
<!ENTITY igrave "&#236;">
<!ENTITY iacute "&#237;">
<!ENTITY icirc "&#238;">
<!ENTITY iuml "&#239;">
<!ENTITY eth "&#240;">
<!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;">
<!ENTITY ograve "&#242;">
<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;">
<!ENTITY ocirc "&#244;">
<!ENTITY otilde "&#245;">
<!ENTITY ouml "&#246;">
<!ENTITY oslash "&#248;">
<!ENTITY ugrave "&#249;">
<!ENTITY uacute "&#250;">
<!ENTITY ucirc "&#251;">
<!ENTITY uuml "&#252;">
<!ENTITY yacute "&#253;">
<!ENTITY thorn "&#254;">
<!ENTITY yuml "&#255;">
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
<!ENTITY iexcl "&#161;">
<!ENTITY cent "&#162;">
<!ENTITY pound "&#163;">
<!ENTITY curren "&#164;">
<!ENTITY yen "&#165;">
<!ENTITY brvbar "&#166;">
<!ENTITY sect "&#167;">
<!ENTITY uml "&#168;">
<!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
<!ENTITY ordf "&#170;">
<!ENTITY laquo "&#171;">
<!ENTITY not "&#172;">
<!ENTITY shy "&#173;">
<!ENTITY reg "&#174;">
<!ENTITY macr "&#175;">
<!ENTITY deg "&#176;">
<!ENTITY plusmn "&#177;">
<!ENTITY sup2 "&#178;">
<!ENTITY sup3 "&#179;">
<!ENTITY acute "&#180;">
<!ENTITY micro "&#181;">
<!ENTITY para "&#182;">
<!ENTITY cedil "&#184;">
<!ENTITY sup1 "&#185;">
<!ENTITY ordm "&#186;">
<!ENTITY raquo "&#187;">
<!ENTITY frac14 "&#188;">
<!ENTITY frac12 "&#189;">
<!ENTITY frac34 "&#190;">
<!ENTITY iquest "&#191;">
<!ENTITY times "&#215;">
<!ENTITY divide "&#247;">
<!ENTITY forall "&#8704;">
<!ENTITY part "&#8706;">
<!ENTITY exist "&#8707;">
<!ENTITY empty "&#8709;">
<!ENTITY nabla "&#8711;">
<!ENTITY isin "&#8712;">
<!ENTITY notin "&#8713;">
<!ENTITY ni "&#8715;">
<!ENTITY prod "&#8719;">
<!ENTITY sum "&#8721;">
<!ENTITY minus "&#8722;">
<!ENTITY lowast "&#8727;">
<!ENTITY radic "&#8730;">
<!ENTITY prop "&#8733;">
<!ENTITY infin "&#8734;">
<!ENTITY ang "&#8736;">
<!ENTITY and "&#8743;">
<!ENTITY or "&#8744;">
<!ENTITY cap "&#8745;">
<!ENTITY cup "&#8746;">
<!ENTITY int "&#8747;">
<!ENTITY there4 "&#8756;">
<!ENTITY sim "&#8764;">
<!ENTITY cong "&#8773;">
<!ENTITY asymp "&#8776;">
<!ENTITY ne "&#8800;">
<!ENTITY equiv "&#8801;">
<!ENTITY le "&#8804;">
<!ENTITY ge "&#8805;">
<!ENTITY sub "&#8834;">
<!ENTITY sup "&#8835;">
<!ENTITY nsub "&#8836;">
<!ENTITY sube "&#8838;">
<!ENTITY supe "&#8839;">
<!ENTITY oplus "&#8853;">
<!ENTITY otimes "&#8855;">
<!ENTITY perp "&#8869;">
<!ENTITY sdot "&#8901;">
<!ENTITY Alpha "&#913;">
<!ENTITY Beta "&#914;">
<!ENTITY Gamma "&#915;">
<!ENTITY Delta "&#916;">
<!ENTITY Epsilon "&#917;">
<!ENTITY Zeta "&#918;">
<!ENTITY Eta "&#919;">
<!ENTITY Theta "&#920;">
<!ENTITY Iota "&#921;">
<!ENTITY Kappa "&#922;">
<!ENTITY Lambda "&#923;">
<!ENTITY Mu "&#924;">
<!ENTITY Nu "&#925;">
<!ENTITY Xi "&#926;">
<!ENTITY Omicron "&#927;">
<!ENTITY Pi "&#928;">
<!ENTITY Rho "&#929;">
<!ENTITY Sigma "&#931;">
<!ENTITY Tau "&#932;">
<!ENTITY Upsilon "&#933;">
<!ENTITY Phi "&#934;">
<!ENTITY Chi "&#935;">
<!ENTITY Psi "&#936;">
<!ENTITY Omega "&#937;">
<!ENTITY alpha "&#945;">
<!ENTITY beta "&#946;">
<!ENTITY gamma "&#947;">
<!ENTITY delta "&#948;">
<!ENTITY epsilon "&#949;">
<!ENTITY zeta "&#950;">
<!ENTITY eta "&#951;">
<!ENTITY theta "&#952;">
<!ENTITY iota "&#953;">
<!ENTITY kappa "&#954;">
<!ENTITY lambda "&#955;">
<!ENTITY mu "&#956;">
<!ENTITY nu "&#957;">
<!ENTITY xi "&#958;">
<!ENTITY omicron "&#959;">
<!ENTITY pi "&#960;">
<!ENTITY rho "&#961;">
<!ENTITY sigmaf "&#962;">
<!ENTITY sigma "&#963;">
<!ENTITY tau "&#964;">
<!ENTITY upsilon "&#965;">
<!ENTITY phi "&#966;">
<!ENTITY chi "&#967;">
<!ENTITY psi "&#968;">
<!ENTITY omega "&#969;">
<!ENTITY thetasym "&#977;">
<!ENTITY upsih "&#978;">
<!ENTITY piv "&#982;">
<!ENTITY OElig "&#338;">
<!ENTITY oelig "&#339;">
<!ENTITY Scaron "&#352;">
<!ENTITY scaron "&#353;">
<!ENTITY Yuml "&#376;">
<!ENTITY fnof "&#402;">
<!ENTITY circ "&#710;">
<!ENTITY tilde "&#732;">
<!ENTITY ensp "&#8194;">
<!ENTITY emsp "&#8195;">
<!ENTITY thinsp "&#8201;">
<!ENTITY zwnj "&#8204;">
<!ENTITY zwj "&#8205;">
<!ENTITY lrm "&#8206;">
<!ENTITY rlm "&#8207;">
<!ENTITY ndash "&#8211;">
<!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;">
<!ENTITY lsquo "&#8216;">
<!ENTITY rsquo "&#8217;">
<!ENTITY sbquo "&#8218;">
<!ENTITY ldquo "&#8220;">
<!ENTITY rdquo "&#8221;">
<!ENTITY bdquo "&#8222;">
<!ENTITY dagger "&#8224;">
<!ENTITY Dagger "&#8225;">
<!ENTITY bull "&#8226;">
<!ENTITY hellip "&#8230;">
<!ENTITY permil "&#8240;">
<!ENTITY prime "&#8242;">
<!ENTITY Prime "&#8243;">
<!ENTITY lsaquo "&#8249;">
<!ENTITY rsaquo "&#8250;">
<!ENTITY oline "&#8254;">
<!ENTITY euro "&#8364;">
<!ENTITY trade "&#8482;">
<!ENTITY larr "&#8592;">
<!ENTITY uarr "&#8593;">
<!ENTITY rarr "&#8594;">
<!ENTITY darr "&#8595;">
<!ENTITY harr "&#8596;">
<!ENTITY crarr "&#8629;">
<!ENTITY lceil "&#8968;">
<!ENTITY rceil "&#8969;">
<!ENTITY lfloor "&#8970;">
<!ENTITY rfloor "&#8971;">
<!ENTITY loz "&#9674;">
<!ENTITY spades "&#9824;">
<!ENTITY clubs "&#9827;">
<!ENTITY hearts "&#9829;">
<!ENTITY diams "&#9830;">
ENTITIES;
```

Comment: excellent, this worked like a charm! solved a bunch of other problems also. In my case I used it to create a XML document like so $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><!DOCTYPE root [$XML_HTML_DEFS]><root></root>", null, false);

Comment: After changing from `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">` to just `<html>`
my page looks odd... no styles or line-breaks now. But did fix it mostly!

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you have some control over the documents to be passed to DOMDocument is to use HTML entities ( `&#160;` ) or unicode characters ( `U+00A0` ) instead of named characters ( `&nbsp;` ).

Assuming the following documents:
Document 1 ( test_1.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>this line has a space ( )</element>
    <element>this line has a non breakin space (&nbsp;)</element>
    <element>this line has an integral symbol (&int;)</element>
</root>
```

Document 2 ( test_2.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>this line has a space (&#32;)</element>
    <element>this line has a non breakin space (&#160;)</element>
    <element>this line has an integral symbol (&#8747;)</element>
</root>
```

Document 3 ( test_3.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>this line has a space ( )</element>
    <element>this line has a non breakin space (U+00A0)</element>
    <element>this line has an integral symbol (U+222B)</element>
</root>
```

And a php file that loads those documents: ( index.php )

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xml_file = file_get_contents( "test_2.xml" );
    $xmlDoc->loadXML( $xml_file );
?>
```

The first document will generate warnings like the following:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity, line: 4 in /path/to/file/index.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'int' not defined in Entity, line: 5 in /path/to/file/index.php on line 5
```

But documents 2 and 3 will be parsed fine.

Reference:

- [freeformatter.com: list of HTML entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)
- [Wikipedia: Numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)
- [Wikipedia: List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Entities_representing_special_characters_in_XHTML)
- [compart: HTML Entities in utf-8](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/html)

Answer (score -2):

```
$textHTML = '&lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt;Dentro da ordem jur&amp;iacute;dica
brasileira.&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;
```

save in the XML file like this:

```
htmlspecialchars($textHTML, ENT_QUOTES);
```

recover the file like this:

```
$doc->load(file.xml);
```